# Cannot get Results from PHP using JQuery Post

Tags: php, jquery, post

sorry I am an amateur coder and learning this as a hobby.  I am not able to get results of the php back to the javascript after I $.post.

1. I know test.php has ran properly with the "Name" passed through, as I've put an SQL update to see the name and time is updated every time I click this button.
2. The page itself, test.php, runs fine on it's own with echo results
3. I just cannot get the result into data and for alert(data) to work.

Edit:  My problem was as Reyaner has pointed out, it will not work on different domains.  Is there any work around?

Javascript

```
$("button").click(function(){
        $.post(
                "http://www.test.com/test.php",  // works
                {name : "Bozmo"},  // works
                function(data){   // does not work !!
                        alert("Data: " + data);
                }
        );
});
```

PHP

```
$name = $_POST["name"]; 
echo $name."is here";
```

Thanks in Advance,
Jimmy

Comment: Did you include the jquery file? and also check your url directory if that was correct..

Comment: calling it from the same domain? if not, it wont work..

Comment: append exit; to end of your php code.

Comment: What is the error in the console?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  Reyaner was right, I was calling from another domain.  Is there anyway around this?

Comment: if its some other domain, check out for some apis related to your requirement, else you cant

Comment: i have already call from same domain in below example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").click(function(){ 
 $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {name : "Bozmo"},
        success: function(data){
            alert("Data: " + data);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");        
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please delete the `<br>` tag because that was not included to the code and it will cause error.

Comment: This works the same.  Unfortunately as Reyaner said above I cannot call from another domain.

Comment: it's means simple write

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$.post("http://www.test.com/test.php", { name : "Bozmo" })
.done(function(data) {
alert("Data: " + data);
});
```